# How to take read all the partitions from eMMC dump

Tags: linux, ext4, embedded, loop-device, vfs

We have Beaglebone Black based custom board with 4GB eMMC and 256MB RAM.
eMMC is partitioned as follows

```
# parted --list
Model: MMC MMC04G (sd/mmc)
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 3842MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name        Flags
 1      131kB   262kB   131kB                
 2      262kB   393kB   131kB                
 3      393kB   524kB   131kB                
 4      524kB   1573kB  1049kB               
 5      1573kB  2621kB  1049kB               
 6      2621kB  3146kB  524kB                
 7      3146kB  3277kB  131kB                
 8      3277kB  8520kB  5243kB               
 9      8520kB  13.8MB  5243kB               
10      13.8MB  19.0MB  5243kB               
11      19.0MB  19.3MB  262kB                
12      19.3MB  19.5MB  262kB                
13      19.5MB  19.8MB  262kB                
14      21.0MB  32.5MB  11.5MB               
15      33.6MB  243MB   210MB   ext4         
16      243MB   453MB   210MB   ext4         
17      453MB   558MB   105MB   ext4         
18      558MB   621MB   62.9MB  ext4         
19      621MB   830MB   210MB   ext4         
20      830MB   867MB   36.7MB  ext4         
21      867MB   3827MB  2960MB  ext4
```

Now we would like to dump eMMC partitions and read data from it. This is mainly for debugging purpose for any field returned boards. 
E.g. I could read one of the partition in binary file and mount it and read its data.

e.g. take partition 20(which is ext4 partition), I could read it from `u-boot` or using `Lauterbach debugger` into filename say `part20.bin`

I can get that file to `Ubuntu PC` and mount it on loop device to get the
The way I did that is as follows

```
cat part20.bin >  part20.iso
sudo losetup /dev/loop0 part20.iso
```

This commands mounts the partition 20 and shows contents of it.

Now to going step further when I read whole eMMC content in binary file using `Lauterbach` debugger. Now I am not sure if I mount all the partitions in the same way as I did before. Infect I got 4gb binary file in my ubuntu PC and tried above commands, it works fine(no error) but I don't see any partitions mounted. I know there are `raw` partitions in eMMC partition table so it might not be possible read all the partitions in the same way, However my question is

Is there a way to see all the partitions from eMMC dump and read data from it ?

Comment: This [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/372024/cant-mount-disk-image/372055#372055) describes how to do that on a msdos partition table. Could it be as simple as just using GPT tools and doing the same??

Comment: Thank you for reply, I think eMMC dump didn't work properly as when I run `fdisk ` I get a message that `image doesn't contain a valid partition table`. Let me re-read and try again.

Comment: fdisk is more for msdos partitions. Think you may need `parted` for gpt partitions.

Comment: I think latest `fdisk` does recognize gpt. I tried with `parted` also and result is same. I opened binary file in binary editor `bless` and it has same content i.e. `0xFE` all over the file which is not possible because indeed eMMC is having data.

Comment: you were right, indeed fdisk didn't recognize the gpt( at-least on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS). After getting right image. I used kpartx to get the partitions mounted on my pc. With lsblk I was able to list the partitions. I will updated it in detailed answer.